# filter an array of objects which contains key value pairs where value is an integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, include

My Array looks like this

```js
filtervalue = xy

arr = [{id:123, name:'xyz'}, {id:122, name:'xyy'}, {id:134, name:'zzz'}]

arr.filter((i) =>
          name.includes(filtervalue)
        );
```

above gives me the expected output as below

```js
[{id:123, name:'xyz'}, {id:122, name:'xyy'}]
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with the id. it gives me an error

> .includes is not a function.

like, when my filterval = 12

expected output should be as below

```js
[{id:123, name:'xyz'}, {id:122, name:'xyy'}]
```

how do i achieve this ?

Comment: I think `name.includes(filtervalue)` should be `i.name.includes(filtervalue)`

Answer (score 0):

Please use filter function like this.

```js
const filtervalue = 12

const arr = [{id:123, name:'xyz'}, {id:122, name:'xyy'}, {id:134, name:'zzz'}]

const result = arr.filter((val) => val.id.toString().includes(filtervalue.toString()))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: i want to filter it by id and achieve the same output

Comment: I updated the code with 'toString' function

Comment: thankyou, totally forgot that there is this option to convert a number to a string

Comment: I hope your work is going well